# Is it possible to have an animation appear on WPF NavigationWindow?

Tags: wpf, animation, navigationwindow

I have a NavigationWindow which hosts a series of Pages.  For design reasons the Pages are fixed at 780x580 but the NavigationWindow can be set to maximize, leaving a lot of black background around my Pages.

I would like to show a fairly simple, unobtrusive animation (just some labels of various opacity/size streaming from side to side) continuously running *behind* all the Pages... the logical place would be the NavigationWindow so that there would be no interruption when the user navigates from page to page.

Neither Blend not Visual Studio give me access to controls when I have the NavigationPage in the designer, so my guess is that I cannot do it that way.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to do this, or a workaround that nets me the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was poking around at this alittle last night, I'll let you know if I come up with anything.  Have you looked at the [MSDN NavigationWindow ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970054.aspx)

Comment: Wow, that example was hard to follow!  However, it does seem to imply I can do what I wanted to do. I'll see if I can glean enough from it to do what I need. Thanks for the link.